# Multiple value field playframework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

What I need here is a multiple value field like in this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/).

Is there another way to do this with Playframework and scala template? If not, how do I get the values in the field once it is populated?

Comment: There is but nobody is going to read the whole tutorial . Explain exactly what is your goal in a more precise fashion and I will be happy to help you

Comment: @Edmondo1984 My goal is to make a field that get multiple values (like the tag field here in stackoverflow, or the gmail field). I wanted to know if there is a way to do it with play.

Comment: @MarouaneLakhal I don't think this is anything to do with Play!, particularly.  What you need is almost certainly going to be client-side, so the question you need to ask is what HTML/JS/CSS you need to serve up to be able to do this.  (And once you've put together something that works, *any* backend would be able to serve it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play and its template system is nothing more than a way for generating required code (in very basic words) so yes it's possible to use this tutorial in Play.

The [tutorial you initially pointed](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/) contains everything you need, although it doesn't describe required JSON format. Fortunately you can check [included demo](http://www.danwellman.co.uk/demos/autocomplete.html?subject=&message=#) to see what they are generating with friends.php

Use Firebug or other similar tool to check what requests are sending to the server when you're starting writing in the `To:` field and also what does it return as a response.

Now only thing you have to do is just create an action in Play which will return data in required format ie:

when it sends a request:

```
http://somedomain.tld/friends.php?callback=jsonp1350036024256&term=m
```

it receives the response (names beginning with given `term`):

```
jsonp1350036024256([{"name":"Mace Windu"},{"name":"Mon Mothma"}])
```

How to prepare the JSON in Play's action is described in [last section of the JSON document](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaJsonRequests)

Comment: Thank you this is what i wanted to know.

Comment: I did understand how the hole thing work but I am still confused about the `term` and `callback`values. How do i get them?